# How to grab the data from System.out as string?

Tags: java, inputstream, stdout

For a sort of IDE-like system I'm writing in java, I want to replicate and display a console working identically to the standard one. Therefore I need a way to read everything that is written to `stdout` and `stderr`.
Is there something similar to the `Process.getInputStream()` function that is applicable to the current Java process and not only to external ones?
Would like to avoid having to change all stdout commands.

Huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
  FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");

  System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));

  // this text will get redirected to youe file
  System.out.println("This is System class!!!");
```

Comment: Ahh so simple >< Been overcomplicating things.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use System.setOut() and System.setErr() to override the default output and error streams with your custom streams.